# Why is sentence ‘a color has blue’ wrong?

Tags: verbs

Why is ‘a color has blue’ wrong but ‘a color is blue’ right?

If ‘blue’ and ‘color’ are defined, isn’t it ‘a color having blue’? A blue color’ is right though.

Or am I approaching it so mathematically?

Comment: Blue, red etc. are colours. so it doesn't make any sense to say 'A colour has blue', and not very much sense to say 'A colour is blue'. You can say 'The colour of [something] is blue'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Dear Bunting, isn’t it weird that the blue color (=the color having blue) is accepted?

Comment: No, it isn't 'weird' at all. _Blue_ (and other colour names) is usually an adjective. _The blue colour_ does not mean _the colour having blue_, it means _the colour described as blue_.

Comment: My dog has fleas.  My dog is a flea. The second sentence is senseless, as is *A color has blue.*  I could say, *Blue has a color.*  That color of course is blue so that's like saying *hot is heat.*

Comment: We never use "has" when describing an entire thing - if the color *is* blue, then the entire color is blue and "the color *has* blue" is incorrect.  Likewise, if Mary *is* my sister (a quality of her entire person), then it is incorrect to say that "Mary *has* my sister."

Comment: Language is not math. You're going to have to stop thinking that way if you're ever going to learn English.

Comment: "*That color is blue.*" would be idiomatic. And you can use an adjective in front of "blue" e.g. *Those houses have **a strange blue** [colour]*.

Answer (score 2):

Blue is an adjective, not a noun.

So *the sky is blue* - adjective describes the sky
but *the sky has blue* - incorrect - the sky cannot possess *blue* as it is not a noun.

Comment: Related: "*I am lost in **the blue of** your eyes*" Maybe *blueness* would be more grammatically correct, but I think it still works. And while I'm at it, "*I am lost in your eyes **of blue**.*" Works even better, and *blue* is still a noun.

Answer (score 2):

As you were told in the comments, blue is an actual colour so it would be strange to say that a colour has a colour, or that blue has blue...

BUT, I would just like to point out that people do use such sentences as

> This colour ***has blue in it***

or

> Most whites that ***have*** a tint of ***blue*** in them

This however is a specific reference to colour of paints, to the pigment composition of a certain colour of paint. On this [site](https://www.resene.co.nz/Colour-Experts/Colour-Experts-answer-questions-55.htm) I found this question about paints:

> My husband has just painted all our doors in Resene Grey Friars. It
> looks way too dark, and looks like a bluey grey. I'm just wondering if
> this colour has blue in it.

It actually means that the certain dye or paint has ***blue pigments*** in it. Just like these:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Blue is not a noun, it is an adjective. And that sentence is wrong grammatically.
It looks like "Blue is blue."